# Is that possible to display jMeter run time in grafana dashboard

Tags: jmeter, grafana, influxdb, influxql, grafana-dashboard

i created a dashboard for display load test results. i used JMeter, influx dB, grafana for that. after that I found a dashboard it is able to fulfill my need. but it's not display respond time correctly.in that case i want to know is that possible to display in grafana panel how much time does JMeter takes for run a script.

I tried it using grafana annunciator panel also. but its not given me right time spent for run that process.

Comment: What is the response time you stored in your InfluxDB and what does Grafana show you? Can you explain the error you get? And how do you query your data?

Comment: actually i created that connection after see this tutorial https://loadium.com/blog/real-time-monitoring-with-jmeter-influxdb-integration .the grafana dashboard is created automatically after i created the connection between j meter and grafana. actually i don't know how show the time that spent to run the load test in JMeter on graphana. Please help me. thankyou so much.